# Convert tensorflow 1 contrib to tensorflow 2 Keras version

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I was in the process of Migrating my code from tf1 to tf2 and I think I managed have to fix most of the issues for running it with tf2. But Got Stuck while migrating it to Tf2 compatible with tfa.seq2seq.LuongAttention and tfa.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper Already replaced contrib to v2 but not sure why its not working.

```
def _single_cell(num_units, keep_prob, device_str=None):
    single_cell = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(num_units)
    if keep_prob < 1.0:
        single_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell=single_cell, input_keep_prob=keep_prob)
    # Device Wrapper
    if device_str:
        single_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DeviceWrapper(single_cell, device_str)
    return single_cell


def create_rnn_cell(num_units, num_layers, keep_prob):
    """Create multi-layer RNN cell."""
    cell_list = []
    for i in range(num_layers):
        single_cell = _single_cell(num_units=num_units, keep_prob=keep_prob)
        cell_list.append(single_cell)
    if len(cell_list) == 1:  # Single layer.
        return cell_list[0]
    else:  # Multi layers
        return tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cell_list)

cell = create_rnn_cell(
            num_units=hparams.num_units,
            num_layers=hparams.num_layers,
            keep_prob=hparams.keep_prob)

encoder_outputs, encoder_state = tf.compat.v1.nn.dynamic_rnn(
                cell,
                encoder_emb_inp,
                dtype=dtype,
                sequence_length=self.batch_input.source_sequence_length,
                time_major=self.time_major)
```

I referred to https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/tree/master/tensorflow_addons/seq2seq and was able to migrate most of the code except these two functions

Answer (score 0):

Few of the libraries in Tensorflow 2.x are moved to some other repository like addons and operation.

Replace `tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper` with `tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper` for more information about library find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/nn/rnn_cell/DropoutWrapper).

Replace `tf.contrib.rnn.DeviceWrapper` with `tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.DeviceWrapper` for more information about library find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/nn/rnn_cell/DeviceWrapper).